# Cannot pass parameter from javascript to JSF Bean using primefaces RemoteCommand

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF site using primeFaces. I cannot get any parameters from my javascript to my bean using P:RemoreCommand. Here is my code:

xhtml:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="scaleLines" actionListener="#{mapBean2.scaleLines}"  update="mapPanel"/>
```

Then later to call it:

```
map.on('viewreset', function(){  
          scaleLines({newZoom:'10'});


           });
```

Session Scoped ManagedBean:

```
public void scaleLines(){

   String newZoom = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("newZoom");

    if(newZoom == null){
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Zoom level is null");
    }
    else{
    Integer newZoomInt = Integer.parseInt(newZoom);
    this.mapzoomLevel = newZoomInt;
    for(ZsyMap1Linetest line : allTestLines){
        line.setWeight(((line.getWeight()*newZoomInt)/(6)));
    }
   }
}
```

This does call the method, but when I attach a debugger, I can see that newZoom is always null meaning that the parameter does not get passed. I hhave read other posts and I can't see why it would not get passed. I also tried this using a JSF managedBean for the backing bean and a CDI named bean, bOth had the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong format. You have to use an array of JS-objects with "name" and "value". I.e. `[{"name":"param1","value":"value1"},...]`

In your case changing the parameters of `scaleLine` to `[{"name":"newZoom","value":"10"}]` should do the trick. Additionally you should surround the key in the JS-object with `""`, otherwise it is no valid JSON.

Comment: I am using LeafletJS. When surrounding in double quotes as suggested, the javascript throws the error TypeError:t.addLayer is not a function. I tried surrounding in single quotes like this: `scaleLines({'name':'newZoom','value':'10'});`  . This produced the same result as before: The Bean method is called, but NewZoom is null.

Comment: Actually , I noticed from my above comment that I had left out the brackets. This seems to work `scaleLines([{'name':'newZoom','value':'10'}]);`

Answer (score -1):

Can you put a square bracket `[]` around the parameters of `scaleLines()` like this `scaleLines([{newZoom:'10'}])`? Also please make sure that `remoteCommand` is inside a `h:form`. If it does not work, as I have not used primefaces for a long time and lots have changed since I last used, you can just use tradition way to communicate js and backbean. That is to have a hidden form of 1 text field and 1 button, and use jquery/js to populate the value `10` to the value of the text field. This text field should bind its value to `newZoom` variable in your bean. Then use jquery/js to click the command button that will  trigger `scaleLines` method. If you dont have to bind text field to a variable on your bean, you can still get the value `10` from requestParameterMap.